# Extracting img urls from webpage using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping

This is an Apps Script that goes through a webpage and collects img urls that are inside some div of a special class.

```
function getIMGs(url){

var url = 'url'

var  result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {
  var doc = Xml.parse(result, true);        
  var bodyHtml = doc.html.body.toXmlString();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(bodyHtml);
  var html = doc.getRootElement();
  var thumbs = getElementsByClassName(html, 'thumb');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (i in Thumbs) {
    var output = '';
    var linksInMenu = getElementsByTagName(thumbs[i], 'img');

    for(i in linksInMenu) {
      output += XmlService.getRawFormat().format(linksInMenu[i]);
    }

    var linkRegExp = /data-src="(.*?)"/;
    var dataSrc = linkRegExp.exec(output);
    sheet.appendRow([dataSrc[1]]);
    }
}
```

So first the code gets the html, and uses an auxiliary function to get certain elements, which look like this:

```
<div class="thumb"><div class="loader"><span class="icon-uniE611"></span></div><img src="//xxx" data-src="https://xxx/8491a83b1cacc2401907997b5b93e433c03c91f.JPG" data-target="#image-slider" data-slide-to="0"></div>
```

Then the code gets the img elements, and finally extracts the data-src address via RegExp.

While this **kinda works**, I have a problem:

1) After 9 loops it crashes, **on the appendRow line**, as the last 4 Thumbs elements don't have data-src, hence what i'm trying to write into the spreadsheet is null.

Any solution for this? I have fixed it for the moment by just doing 9 iterations only of the For loop, but this is far from optimal, as it's not automated and required me to go through the page to count the elements with data-src.

Also, any suggestion of a more elegant solution will be appreciated! I will be really grateful for any helping hand!

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, didn't know, Fixed!

Comment: If `dataSrc[1]` results in `null`, you could do a conditional test before using the `append()` method:  `if (dataSrc[1] === null) {continue};`  Continue to loop it the value is null.